# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

The following returns `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type`

```
var Products = from s in db.Products where 
          ( from c in s.Manufacturers
  where (x => (from man in model.man where man.HasValue select man.Value).Contains(c.ManufacturerID)
  select c).Any()
  select s;
```

While this just works

```
if (model.man != null)
   {
        var students = from s in db.Products
                       where (from c in s.Manufacturers
                       where model.man.Contains(c.ManufacturerID)
                       select c).Any()
                       select s;
   }
```

What am i doing wrong in the first case?
The model.man is declared as

```
public int?[] man { get; set; }
```

Comment: Why you have that `x =>` there in the first query? Remove that since that is a query syntax and not method syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use null conditional access instead (in C# 6)

```
var students = from s in db.Products
               where (from c in s.Manufacturers
               where model.man?.Contains(c.ManufacturerID) ?? false
               select c).Any()
               select s;
```

Edit: added `?? false` because there is no implicit conversion between `bool` and `bool?`

Answer (score 0):

Like Rahul says, you cannot mix query and method syntax. This should compile:

```
 var Products = from s in db.Products
                       where(from c in s.Manufacturers
                             where (from man in model.man
                                    where man.HasValue
                                    select man.Value)
                                    .Contains(c.ManufacturerID)
                             select c).Any()
                       select s;
```

If you want to use a lambda expression at that particular point, you can always chain it with a period, e.g.:

```
var Products = from s in db.Products
                           where(s.Manufacturers
                           .Where(c => (from man in model.man
                               where man.HasValue
                               select man.Value)
                               .Contains(c.ManufacturerID))).Any()
                           select s;
```

Although as personal preference (readability), I'd rather not mix the two syntaxes. If you are unfamiliar with method syntax, ReSharper does provide the option to convert query to method chain (hammer icon).

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same error in a simple for loop. The error was due to the misplaced  "=" symbol.

It was

```
 for(int i=10;i=>0;i--)
{
 //your code
}
```

If you look at the code closely you can see that = is placed in front of >.
It should be **less than or equal to that is >=**.

The correct code should be

```
for(int i=10;i>=0;i--)
    {
     //your code
    }
```

I hope this might help someone.